# Can a Connection Be Double DNAT Through an Iptables Rule

Tags: string, iptables, nat

so say for instance i have an iptables rule that is of the sort

```
 iptables -I PREROUTING 1 -p udp 1000 -j DNAT --to-dest 192.168.1.10:1010
```

is there a way that i can midway through the connection based on say a u32 match or a string match further redirect the incoming ports connection to another ip

so in laymans terms i have forwarded port 1000 to an internal ip and port, and upon transmission of a packet that meets a certain criteria "re DNAT" that connection to another internal ip

I would think that I could insert this rule before hand and effectuate what i want but it consistently just skips over the rule

```
 iptables -I PREROUTING 1 -p udp 1000 -m string --algo bm "stringtomatch" -j DNAT --to-dest 192.168.1.100:1010
```

should it maybe be after... and should i change the port on the secondary rule to the changed port address?

Comment: Not that proficient with this, but would say the second rule should be before the first one (to have a chance to override it). Did you try to use e.g. `LOG` to check the string matching part actually works?

Comment: right thats what the "insert this rule beforehand" implied was that it was inserted on top of the stack of iptables rules... it seems that once a connection is nat-ed its stuck... idk